# Average a half of number of a grouped column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Below I defined two dataframes, input and output.
`df_input`:

- Column `A` which is to be grouped.
- Column `B` is a sort of index withing groups of `A`, enumeration.
- Column `C` contains elements to be summed up.

`df_output`:

- Column `D` with the calculated average

Within each group of `A` take average over elements of `C`, but only the first half of those. If the number of elements is odd ceil it.
This is just a simplified problem of some huge dataset. And this is how I did solve it so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_input = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 
               "B": [2,1,1,3,2,4,2,1,3],
               "C": [1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4]})

df_output = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 
                      "B": [2,1,1,3,2,4,2,1,3],
                      "C": [1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4],
                      "D": [1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4]})

df = df_input.copy()

df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
df['E'] = np.ceil(df['A'] / 2)  # this is number of elements to sum up withing group 'A'
df['G'] = df['C'] / df['E'] # this is element to be included or not inside the sum
df['H'] = np.where(df['E'] >= df['B'], df['G'], 0)
df['D'] = df.groupby('A')['H'].transform('sum')
```

I'm hoping to get this done in a more neat and one-liner(s) type of way...please :)